# Strange operator[] behavior

Tags: c++, operators

When I was writing a program, I made a typo. I have wrote `i[data]` instead `data[i]`. However the program was successful compiled and worked right.

Operator[] behavior with arrays:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  int data[] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
  
  cout << data[6] << endl; // prints 6
  cout << 6[data]; // prints 6
  return 0;
}
```

Similar operator[] behavior with pointers:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  char* str = "Hello, world!";
  
  cout << str[9] << endl; //prints 'r'
  cout << 9[str]; //prints 'r'
  return 0;
}
```

Why `data[i]` equals `i[data]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`i[data]` is the same as `*(i + data)`

`data[i]` is the same as `*(data + i)`

And `data + i` is equal to `i + data`.